# Show gaps between dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I show the remaining/complementary dates in mysql?

For example in my table that has 2 columns, a snapshot for 
`from_date>14-06-2014 and to_date<01-07-2014`

would give this output:

```
From date   || To_date
15-06-2014  || 20-06-2014
23-06-2014  || 27-06-2014 
29-06-2014  || 30-06-2014
```

I would like to be able to show the dates that we have a gap and no records exist, like this:

```
2 //21-06-2014 - 23-06-2014
1 //28-06-2014
```

Is this possible?
Thank you

Comment: Have a look at [the sql of gaps and islands](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/)  It's written for SQL Server, but some of the variants will work for MySQL.  (Re-opened because the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731343/find-date-gaps-with-mysql) pointed to a table with dates, while this one contains date ranges.)

Comment: Those are not dates (in an SQL sense)

Comment: @Strawberry, everything that will provide the needed information in any format will do.

Comment: That sounds deep - I've no idea what it means :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

along those lines:

```
drop table if exists dates;
create table dates (d_from date, d_to date);
insert into dates values 
('2014-06-15'  , '2014-06-20'),
('2014-06-23'  , '2014-06-27' ),
('2014-06-29'  , '2014-06-30' );

select low.d_to, high.d_from, to_days(high.d_from) - to_days(low.d_to) - 1 as gap

from dates low, dates high
where high.d_from = (select min(d_from) from dates where d_from > low.d_to)
;
```

Which means: join the table to itself on adjacent end/start dates and compute the difference.

```
+------------+------------+------+
| d_to       | d_from     | gap  |
+------------+------------+------+
| 2014-06-20 | 2014-06-23 |    2 |
| 2014-06-27 | 2014-06-29 |    1 |
+------------+------------+------+
```