# How to fetch users who does not have reports for 6 consecutive months using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm developing a report system, and I want to fetch users who did not report for six (6) consecutive months. How do I achieve this?

I've tried the code below but I'm not getting the desired output. There is also a problem. Let's say the date interval is 12 months. How can I determine if there is no report for 6 consecutive months?

```
$dateStart = '2018-10-31';
$dateEnd = '2019-03-31';

$intervals = Carbon::parse($dateStart)->diffInMonths($dateEnd);

$users = $users->whereDoesntHave('reports', function($query) use($intervals) {

    for ($i = 5; $i >= 0; $i--) { 

        $firstMonth = Carbon::parse($dateEnd)->subMonthsNoOverflow($intervals);

        $query->where('date', '>=', $firstMonth->format('Y-m-d'))->where('date', '<=', $dateEnd);
    }

});
```

Comment: May this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/24100455/8068675

Comment: what are you using laravel eloquent or query builder to fetch data.

Comment: @SurenderSinghRawat Im using eloquent.

Comment: @cbaconnier Thanks but how can I achieve that using eloquent?

Comment: @Jearson In my opinion, before using Eloquent, you need to know what's the SQL query result you expect. Once you have a working query that correspond to your needs it will be easier to translate it to Eloquent. The query seems complicated with Eloquent, you probably may ending by using [raw expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I will do is that I will create a loop per month based on the start and end date, then check if he did not have a report for that month. If it doesn't have a report for that month, I will increment a counter, and if that counter reaches 6 counts, exit the loop and the condition was satisfied.

Below is the basic idea:

```
$dateStart = '2018-10-31';
$dateEnd = '2019-10-31';

$count = 0;
$no_report_for_6_consecutive_months = 0 ;

startloop
   $have_report = Model::whereMonth('date_column', $date_of_loop->format('m'))->get();

   if($have_report->count()){
      $count = 0;
   }
   else{
      $count++;
   }

   if($count==6){
     $no_report_for_6_consecutive_months = 1 ;
     break;
   }
endloop
```

Comment: Thanks. But the condition should be 6 consecutive months.

Comment: Thanks for the concept. I got it.

Comment: Good to know you got the logic. Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

You have to find distinct users who report for six (6) consecutive and get difference with all users.

```
$enddate = 2019-04-15;
$startdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-6 months", strtotime($enddate)));
$users = User::all();
$usersIdArray = $users->pluck("id")->all();
$reportedBy = Report::where('date', '>=', $startdate)
                           ->where('date', '<=', $enddate)
                           ->distinct("user_id")->get();

$reportedByIdArray = $reportedBy ->pluck("id")->all();

$notReportedByIdArray = array_values(array_diff($usersIdArray , $reportedByIdArray));
$notREportedUsers = User::whereIn(id", $notReportedByIdArray)->get();
//its a way but not tested
```

Comment: you have to set start date and end date ... from your inputs

Comment: But what if the months would be 12 months. How can I know if the user does not have reports for 6 months

Comment: you have to get one input date (may be end date) and  calculate start date with 6 month interval

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the query from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24100455/8068675)

I believe the query can be wrote cleaner. I will let you do this if you want to.

```
App\User::select('*')
    ->from(\DB::raw("(select 
                          low.*,
                          low.`date` as date_start,
                          high.`date` as date_end,
                          to_days(high.`date`) - to_days(low.`date`) as day_gap,
                          period_diff(date_format(high.`date`, '%Y%m'),
                          date_format(low.`date`, '%Y%m')) as month_gap
                      from reports low, reports high 
                      where high.`date` =
                          (select 
                              min(`date`) 
                          from reports 
                          where 
                              `date` > low.`date` 
                              and low.user_id = high.user_id
                          )
                      ) as d") 
    )->get();
```

Now you will get all the users with 4 extra fields: **date_start**; **date_end**, **day_gap** and **month_gap**

If you want the users with a month gap of 6 months you can do this:

```
App\User::select('*')
    ->from(\DB::raw("..."))
    ->where('month_gap', '>=', 6)
    ->get();
```